# Pipelining in a thread and in an object using a timer

Tags: delphi, pipeline, delphi-xe6

My application has an object which monitors output and errors from a command prompt process it creates. I have two implementations of this, one of which runs in a thread, the other runs using a TTimer component which waits 50 milliseconds before calling the OnTimer event again.

The thread approach at no point returns output/error text from the process whereas the timer approach does return output/error text but not necessarily in the right order (I suspect there is a build up in the pipe hence why I want to use threads to reduce the time between pipe checks).

Does anyone have a suggestion which would allow me to monitor my output/error pipes as frequently as possible but isnt a massive CPU drain?

Timer Code:

```
procedure TCmdPipeliner.OnReadTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  ReadPipeResult, ErrorPipeResult : string;
begin

  // Read in pipe data
  ReadPipeResult := Self.ReadPipeContent;
  ErrorPipeResult := Self.ErrorPipeContent;

  if (ReadPipeResult <> '') and (Assigned(Self.FOnPipeRead)) then Self.FOnPipeRead(Self, ReadPipeResult);
  if (ErrorPipeResult <> '') and (Assigned(Self.FOnPipeError)) then Self.FOnPipeError(Self, ErrorPipeResult);

end;
```

Thread Code:

```
procedure TCmdPipeliner.Execute;
var
  ReadPipeResult, ErrorPipeResult : string;
begin

  while not(Self.Terminated) do
    begin

      // Read in pipe data
      ReadPipeResult := Self.ReadPipeContent;
      ErrorPipeResult := Self.ErrorPipeContent;

      if (ReadPipeResult <> '') and (Assigned(Self.FOnPipeRead)) then Self.FOnPipeRead(Self, ReadPipeResult);
      if (ErrorPipeResult <> '') and (Assigned(Self.FOnPipeError)) then Self.FOnPipeError(Self, ErrorPipeResult);

      sleep(1);

    end;
  {end while}

end;
```

I have tried to use 'synchronize' but with no luck;

```
  if (ErrorPipeResult <> '') then
    if (Assigned(Self.FOnPipeError)) then
      Synchronize(procedure
        begin
          Self.FOnPipeError(Self, ErrorPipeResult);
        end);

  if (ReadPipeResult <> '') then
    if (Assigned(Self.FOnPipeRead)) then
      Synchronize(procedure
        begin
          Self.FOnPipeRead(Self, ReadPipeResult);
        end);
```

Comment: You should write 1000 times "Application.ProcessMessages within a thread is EVIL!" :o)

Comment: @SirRufo I'm aware its not great haha! But want to have a working solution first and it was left over from debugging! Have removed it now.

Comment: Keep an eye on this http://www.delphipraxis.net/1284887-post7.html (german forum link)

Comment: You can presumably use async IO to avoid polling.